# Run code EXCEPT when new rows are added to the table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a little piece of code that monitors cells in the 'Y' column for changes and if there is a change then the main bit of code runs.

Is it possible to run the code as usual EXCEPT when a new row is added? (i.e. if the user right clicks on the row number on the left and clicks 'insert' - I do not want the code to run as in the users eyes nothing has been added to the cell in column Y.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("Y2:Y5000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Call Reminder
    End If
End Sub
```

If you need to see further code then please say.

Thanks

Comment: Lets assum, Y is your address col, and A is Name col... Now, cant you amend the code to make sure unless there is a Name only then go and check the address and then remind. basically instead of a single column condition, what if we have two column condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *prevent* the event running, but you can *ignore* the case where an entire row is inserted.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count < Me.Columns.Count Then
        ' Your existing code here

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice @chrisneilsen! Way more elegant way of doing the same as what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. It is based on capturing the previous state of the range, thus if you add a new row the past is not the same as range now. Not the neatest code I've done but you'll get the idea and will know how to tweak it. Remember to store it inside the sheet objects:

```
'use global to store the address of current range
Dim myRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    'have to initialize the global before first usage
    Set myRange = Range("Y2:Y5000")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tempRange As Range
    Set tempRange = Range("Y2:Y5000")

        'compare the range addresses, if don't match (won't match when adding a row or column because the myRange address has changed)
        If Not Intersect(tempRange, Target) Is Nothing And myRange.Address = tempRange.Address Then
            Call Reminder
        End If

        'reset the range of global
        Set myRange = tempRange
End Sub
```